# cookies system - security

Tags: php, security, cookies

I have a method where i check the username and password(hash+salt) is correct. After that, and if the user have acess i do:

```
 if(isset($remember) && $remember == '1') {
        setcookie('email', $email,  time()+60*60*24*100);
    }
    else {
        setcookie('email', $email, time()+3600);
    }
```

My question is about security issues.  the code above is insecure ?  It is needed something like a signature  ?

for example:

```
$user_email = $email;
$hash = sha1(rand(0,500).microtime());
$signature = sha1($hash . $user_email); 
$cookie = base64_encode($signature . "-" . $hash . "-" . $user_email);
setcookie('authentication', $cookie);
```

What do you think ?

Comment: How do you check if somebody is logged in?

Comment: well, i only check if the cookie was defined (isset) or empty

Comment: Oh that's very insecure because it is very simple to manually set a cookie in the browser!!

Comment: why don't you use $_SESSIONS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anecdote time: Back around 2002 I was looking at a packet dump from my school's network and told them that they needed to fix their grades, attendance, student information, everything-under-the-sun system. The way they had it set up was such that after a user authenticated, the system would set a cookie with just the user name and an end-of-session expiry. I fired up a browser, picked a username (first initial, last name), and set that as a cookie. I had access.

What they should have done was set a random 128 number and kept track of that in the server (number, corresponding user, timeout value).

See also

- [Good session practices](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41/good-session-practices).
- [How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).

Answer (score 3):

You need to be verifying a random generated hash or something server-side.  A user can adjust data all the want, and send whatever back for a cookie data.  With your current scheme, it seems that it would be easy to specify whatever user they wanted.  Scary.

When they login, stick an authentication key in the database, along with IP, UserAgent, and Expiration.  If they try to use your site and the IP or UserAgent are different, or the key is expired, force a logout.

Answer (score 0):

In order to easily prevent the user from altering the values of the cookies, you can use [this class](http://pastie.org/2810850) found on the web. It will write a cookie containing a hash corresponding to the "sum" of all the cookies's values, so if you change a data, the hash will be incorrect.

Only three methods are needed:
`Cookie::set(cookie_name, value)`,
`Cookie::get(cookie_name)` and
`Cookie::reset()`.